# Register Checkin Policy for 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to create a TFS Checkin policy extension for use within Visual Studio 2017. The extension itself already works well for VS2015 downwards (I'm attempting to update the Spartez extension as a prelude to a PR)

For some reason, whenever I try to run it in the Experimental Instance, it never seems to load the policy.

[image: Extension Installed]

[image: Extension Not Loaded]

The PkgDef reads:

```
[$RootKey$\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
"Spartez.TFS4JIRA.CheckInPolicy"="$PackageFolder$\Spartez.TFS4JIRA.CheckInPolicy.dll"
```

And the Manifest is as below:

```
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
    <Metadata>
        <Identity Id="e27e3a03-d421-4908-8c6c-bc68a9981069" Version="1.1.4" Language="en-US" Publisher="Spartez" />
        <DisplayName>Spartez Issue Key Checkins Policy</DisplayName>
        <Description xml:space="preserve">Issue Key Checkins Policy by Spartez.</Description>
        <License>License.txt</License>
    </Metadata>
    <Installation>
        <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0]" />
    </Installation>
    <Dependencies>
        <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Assets>
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="File" Path="policies.pkgdef" />
    </Assets>
    <Prerequisites>
        <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
    </Prerequisites>
</PackageManifest>
```

VS 2017 has moved a fair amount around in terms of the Registry settings. Has the registry location for tfs extensions changed?

Comment: For the most part, the contents of the registry haven't changed, except that what used to be in the machine registry is now in a private registry.  That said, I can't speak to the keys you're writing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with this for a few hours. I fixed it by upgrading all of my TFS and Visual Studio Nuget packages referenced by my custom policy project to the latest preview release (v15.113.0-preview):

- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient

A couple notes:

- My extension broke after updating in VS2015. The Nuget packages don't appear to be backward compatible.
- You can have an older version installed in VS2015 alongside the new version installed in VS2017. This is what I'm planning to do until my team has fully converted to 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following article 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies

> Visual Studio 2017 : Check-in policies in Visual Studio 2017 must be set through Team Explorer, tf.exe, or through registry keys declared in the pkgdef of a Visual Studio extension. Policies only apply a single installation of Visual Studio 2017 on your computer. If you have mulitple installations of Visual Studio 2017, you'll need to set the check-in policy on each installation.